# Как избежать торможения сколл-слайдера от многоразовых кликов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, создал стролл-слайдер на сайте (делаю анимацию на скролле, а не перемещаю элементы) и есть проблема, что при многоразовом клике он лагает. Лаги такие:
если много раз кликнуть в 1 соторону - он тормозит,
если кликнуть когда слайдер на 0 или максимальном скролле (например в лево на нулевом), то при клике вправо он ещё будет ждать секунду и тогда прокрутит.

Сразу извиняюсь за лишний код и кривой пример, работаю с sass и там такое.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.products-arrow').on('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($(this).data('direсtion') == 'left') $('.products-slider').animate({scrollLeft: $('.products-slider').scrollLeft() - 175}, 1000);
        if($(this).data('direсtion') == 'right') $('.products-slider').animate({scrollLeft: $('.products-slider').scrollLeft() + 175}, 1000);
    });
})
```

```css
#products > .wr .row .colum {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; }

#products {
  min-height: 220px; }
  #products > .wr {
    max-width: 1070px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding: 40px 20px; }
    #products > .wr .row .colum .products-arrow {
      min-width: 35px;
      min-height: 35px;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      color: black;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      background-color: #393b42;
      transition: 0.5s; }
      #products > .wr .row .colum .products-arrow:hover {
        background-color: #a4a8b1; }
    #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) {
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      max-width: 875px;
      width: 80%;
      min-width: 175px;
      max-height: 130px; }
      @media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
        #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) {
          width: 175px; } }
      #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider {
        max-height: 130px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden; }
        #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider .product-item {
          min-width: 175px;
          margin-right: 20px;
          height: 130px;
          position: relative;
          background: red;
          background-size: contain; }
          #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider .product-item .decoration-shadow {
            position: absolute;
            min-height: 25px;
            max-width: 100%;
            bottom: -10px;
            left: -10px; }
          #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider .product-item .decoration-border {
            max-width: 2px;
            max-height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="products">
    <div class="wr">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="colum">
                <a href="#" data-direсtion="left" class="products-arrow">l</a>
            </div>
            <div class="colum">
                <div class="products-slider">
                    <div class="product-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="colum">
                <a href="#" data-direсtion="right" class="products-arrow">r</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Останавливайте предыдущую анимацию, перед началом новой.

```
.stop()
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('.products-arrow').on('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($(this).data('direсtion') == 'left') $('.products-slider').stop().animate({scrollLeft: $('.products-slider').scrollLeft() - 175}, 1000);
        if($(this).data('direсtion') == 'right') $('.products-slider').stop().animate({scrollLeft: $('.products-slider').scrollLeft() + 175}, 1000);
    });
})
```

```css
#products > .wr .row .colum {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; }

#products {
  min-height: 220px; }
  #products > .wr {
    max-width: 1070px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding: 40px 20px; }
    #products > .wr .row .colum .products-arrow {
      min-width: 35px;
      min-height: 35px;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      color: black;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      background-color: #393b42;
      transition: 0.5s; }
      #products > .wr .row .colum .products-arrow:hover {
        background-color: #a4a8b1; }
    #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) {
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      max-width: 875px;
      width: 80%;
      min-width: 175px;
      max-height: 130px; }
      @media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
        #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) {
          width: 175px; } }
      #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider {
        max-height: 130px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden; }
        #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider .product-item {
          min-width: 175px;
          margin-right: 20px;
          height: 130px;
          position: relative;
          background: red;
          background-size: contain; }
          #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider .product-item .decoration-shadow {
            position: absolute;
            min-height: 25px;
            max-width: 100%;
            bottom: -10px;
            left: -10px; }
          #products > .wr .row .colum:nth-child(2) .products-slider .product-item .decoration-border {
            max-width: 2px;
            max-height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="products">
    <div class="wr">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="colum">
                <a href="#" data-direсtion="left" class="products-arrow">l</a>
            </div>
            <div class="colum">
                <div class="products-slider">
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <img class="decoration-shadow" src="css/img/decoration/product-shadow.png">
                        <img class="decoration-border" src="css/img/decoration/decoration-border-slider.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <img class="decoration-shadow" src="css/img/decoration/product-shadow.png">
                        <img class="decoration-border" src="css/img/decoration/decoration-border-slider.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <img class="decoration-shadow" src="css/img/decoration/product-shadow.png">
                        <img class="decoration-border" src="css/img/decoration/decoration-border-slider.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <img class="decoration-shadow" src="css/img/decoration/product-shadow.png">
                        <img class="decoration-border" src="css/img/decoration/decoration-border-slider.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <img class="decoration-shadow" src="css/img/decoration/product-shadow.png">
                        <img class="decoration-border" src="css/img/decoration/decoration-border-slider.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <img class="decoration-shadow" src="css/img/decoration/product-shadow.png">
                        <img class="decoration-border" src="css/img/decoration/decoration-border-slider.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="colum">
                <a href="#" data-direсtion="right" class="products-arrow">r</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: куда именно стоп надо вставить?

Comment: поставил в начало функции, но тогда оно затормаживается на секунду и дальше продолжает если клик быстрее секунды

Comment: Я же привёл Вам готовый код.

Comment: если клацать много раз - тормозит